# Julia Flux error: MethodError: no method matching *(::Chain{Tuple{Conv{2,4,typeof(identity),Array{Float32,4},Array{Float32,1}},var"#13#15"}}, ::Int64)

Tags: julia, flux.jl

```
using Flux
using Flux:@functor
function ConvBlock(inc,out,k,s,p,use_act)
    return Chain(
        Conv((k,k),inc=>out,stride = s,pad = p,bias=true),
        use_act ? x -> leakyrelu.(x,0.2) : x -> x
    )
end
mutable struct DenseResidualBlock
    residual_beta
    blocks
end

@functor DenseResidualBlock

function DenseResidualBlock(inc,c = 32,residual_beta = 0.2)
    blocks = []
    for i in 0:4
        in_channels = inc + c*i
        out_channels = i<=3 ? c : inc
        use_act = i<=3 ? true : false
        push!(blocks,ConvBlock(in_channels,out_channels,3,1,1,use_act))
    end

    return DenseResidualBlock(residual_beta,blocks)
end

function (m::DenseResidualBlock)(x) 
    new_inputs = x
    local out,new_inputs
    for block in m.blocks
        out = block(new_inputs)
        new_inputs = cat(new_inputs,out,dims=3)
    end
    return m.residual_beta * out + x
end
```

When I run this

> drb = DenseResidualBlock(64)

I get this error
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching *(::Chain{Tuple{Conv{2,4,typeof(identity),Array{Float32,4},Array{Float32,1}},var"#13#15"}}, ::Int64)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an ambiguity in your code when `DenseResidualBlock` is called with two arguments. It could either construct the structure DenseResidualBlock directly or call `DenseResidualBlock(inc,c)` with `residual_beta = 0.2`. If you use keyword arguments for `DenseResidualBlock(inc; c = 32,residual_beta = 0.2)` this  ambiguity is lifted.

The error message indicated that at the line `in_channels = inc + c*i` the parameter `c` is not a number as expected but a `Flux.Chain` which cannot be multiplied by a number.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
function DenseResidualBlock(inc;c = 32,residual_beta = 0.2)
```

instead of

```
function DenseResidualBlock(inc,c = 32,residual_beta = 0.2)
```